# Date and Time Field Issue in Sites

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

I have create a date and time fields in VF Page.It shows correct org time(Australia) in vf page but in Sites its showing different time. How can solve this issues. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here

```
<apex:inputField value="{!cases.Original_Booking_Date_Time__c}" required="true"/>
```

VF Page
[image]

Sites[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check is the Time Zone of the special User that the Site runs under.

Open your Site's detail page and click "Public Access Settings". Then on the Profile page click "View Users" then click on the single User that appears. Check (and correct if wrong) the Time Zone set for that User (which will have priority for access via the Site).